# Python 3.5 Dropbox API modified date doesn't update

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox

I'm writing a script in python3.5 that needs to check if the file on dropbox is 
newer then a local file. If the file is newer, it needs to download the file.

The problem I'm having is that the date on the server doesn't seem to update. Is it possible that it only update on certain times?

```
code snippet:
    def check_if_needed(dbx):
        server_date = dbx.files_get_metadata('/Verlichting.zip').server_modified
        version_epoch = os.path.getmtime('versie.txt')
        version_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(version_epoch)

        print (server_date)
        print (version_date)

    if (version_date < server_date):
        return True


    return False
```

output:
    2016-10-10 13:05:35
    2016-10-10 15:04:25.861405

what it should be:
2016-10-10-15:10:00
2016-10-10 15:04:25.861405

So it returns False, while it has to be True.

I have updated the file on dropbox a couple of times, but it stil doesn't update. I have also looked on the internet but I couldn't find anything. Also I doesn't use the dropbox client, but directly in the browser, and yes I'm updating the file in the Apps folder created by dropbox ;)
If more information is needed, let me know!

Anyone able to help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the difference between timezones. I'm in GMT +2 while dropbox is GMT +0. So I chanced this line

```
version_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(version_epoch) - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
```

Now it works perfectly.